# Why does the ternary operator turn (... ? int : unsigned long long) into int when an implicit conversion is involved?

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, integer-promotion

When I run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo.h>
#include <type_traits>

struct S { operator unsigned long long() const { return 3ULL << 30; } };

int main()
{
    printf("%s, 0x%llX, %d\n",
        typeid(true ? S() : 0).name(),
            (unsigned long long)(1 ? S() : 0),
        std::is_same<
            std::common_type<int, unsigned long long>::type,
            unsigned long long
        >::value);
}
```

I expect to get back `unsigned long long, 0xC0000000, 1`.

However, I get back `int, 0xFFFFFFFFC0000000, 1`. Why?

The way I see it, the `0` should be converted to `unsigned long long`, because the [conversion ranks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) are as follows:

```
rank(int) < rank(long) < rank(long long) = rank(unsigned long long)
```

Yet I see a direct conversion of `unsigned long long` to `int`, which I'm struggling to justify...

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ gives a warning in this case.

Comment: @Phil1970: Wait, really? I'm not getting anything. What warning do you get?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler sees `S` and `int`, not `unsigned long long` and `int`.

It doesn't go through all possible *pairs* of conversions to pick the best one when a class type is involved, because it *can't* do that in general, because a conversion operator might be *templated*, and the rules should not change depending on whether that is the case or not.

All it can do is tell if one type is convertible to the other, and in this case, that means it detects that `S` is convertible to `int`, so it performs that conversion without integer promotion ranks entering the picture at all.